# plugin HTML5 video for CKEDITOR doesn't a button upload video?

Tags: php, ckeditor, html5-video

Ckeditor 4.1 with plugin HTML5 video doesn't a button upload video?

Installation

> 1. Extract the contents of the file into the "plugins" folder of CKEditor.
> 2. In the CKEditor configuration file (config.js) add the following code: config.extraPlugins = 'video';
> 3. In your toolbar configuration, add a new 'Video' item in the place where you want the button to show up.

I have a problem HTML5 video properties doesn't have a button upload same the picture.

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2013, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

    config.extraPlugins = 'image';
    config.extraPlugins = 'video';
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../admin/ckupload.php';
};
```

Toolbar menu

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'con_detail', {
    toolbar: [                                                                  
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Video', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
    ]

    });

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

add this to show server-button:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{

UploadUrl : 'upload.php',
filebrowserUploadUrl : 'upload.php',
filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'upload.php',

});
```